# Paging and sorting in sharepoint BCS

Tags: bcs

I saw [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/paging-and-sorting-with-bcs/) about Paging and sorting and tried to do simiral thing in my project. But failed to do so. Everything works fine apart from instead of getting the value i get the parameter name. forexample the parameter name dvt_sortfield instead of getting its value, i get that exact string as {dvt_sortfield} back to my service Readlist method. Following is my View xml definition

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" Description="" ListDisplayName="" 
    PartOrder="2" Default="TRUE" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True" IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True"
    UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" ExportControlledProperties="False" IsIncludedFilter="" 
    DataSourceID="" Title="BDC_TEST06" ViewFlag="25165829" NoDefaultStyle="" AllowConnect="True" 
    DisplayName="Entity1 List" PageType="PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW" FrameState="Normal" 
    CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itebl.png" PageSize="-1" 
    PartImageLarge="/_layouts/images/itebl.png" AsyncRefresh="False" ExportMode="NonSensitiveData"
    Dir="Default" DetailLink="/Lists/BDC_TEST06" ShowWithSampleData="False" 
    ListId="da8b9fec-e2fd-455f-937b-ec2409ba4ea8" ListName="{DA8B9FEC-E2FD-455F-937B-EC2409BA4EA8}"
    FrameType="Default" PartImageSmall="" IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" 
    AllowEdit="True" ViewGuid="{4C323A00-609D-40CD-8F62-DC2374D3AAF9}" AutoRefresh="False" 
    AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="True" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
    ViewContentTypeId="0x" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." 
    HelpMode="Modeless" ListUrl="" ID="g_4c323a00_609d_40cd_8f62_dc2374d3aaf9" 
    ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True" 
    TitleUrl="/Lists/BDC_TEST06" ManualRefresh="False" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" 
    __WebPartId="{4C323A00-609D-40CD-8F62-DC2374D3AAF9}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" 
    __designer:CustomXsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="">
<ParameterBindings>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
</ParameterBindings>
<XmlDefinition>
<View Name="{4C323A00-609D-40CD-8F62-DC2374D3AAF9}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="Entity1 List" Url="/Lists/BDC_TEST06/ReadList.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
<Method Name="ReadList"> <Filter Name="FilterPageNumber" Value="30"/>
<Filter Name="FilterRowNumber" Value="1"/>
<Filter Name="FilterSortColumn" Value="{$dvt_sortfield}"/>
<Filter Name="FilterSortDir" Value="{$dvt_sortdir}"/>
</Method>
<Query>
    <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name="Identifier1"/> </OrderBy>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="Identifier1" ListItemMenu="TRUE" LinkToItem="TRUE"/>
<FieldRef Name="Message"/>
</ViewFields>
<RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
<Aggregations Value="Off"/> <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
</View>
</XmlDefinition>
<DataFields> </DataFields> 
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to fix my problem. I had to recreate the external list to get the value of those parameters instead of getting their names.

My advice would be if you make any changes to your Service Method (add/delete parameters) and having issues with it after the change then always try with creating a new external list for debug.