# Problem with performance of External List

Tags: development, performance, external-list

In my company a person which are Administraiting the CRM Microsoft Dinamics give me one of External list with a Vacation of Workers in Company. I try first with list local in my project, and this list work and refresh after one secounds, and have got 1024 eements. I try conect with my proyect a External List from CRM and its take a ot of time because it's take about after conect this list with my project 60 secounds. It's more approximately 60 times then in the first time. How should I make it faster, and upgrade the performance of my project. Please Help

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd suggest is to implement paging in your BCS Selectors, as by default the Selector will be getting all elements every time the list is refreshed - and it doesn't cache *at all* - which is a bit of a shame, but makes sense when you think about it.

This will give you the most immediate benefit. Take a look at [this question about External List paging](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/paging-and-sorting-with-bcs) on this site to give some details on how to do this.

After that is done, then you'll need to look more deeply into optimising what you've done. But, this single thing should give you a big improvement.

Comment: But I must told I rendering this On ASP Calendar at method Calendar1_DayRender. I must ask how should I give a paging to ASP Calendar render? Have You got any Idea ? :) Thank You very much that fast replay :)

Comment: If that's the case, then I'd suggest adding a filter method to the external entity of `Date` or some such, so that it only returns results for that day, rather than all events and then filtering them as I'm guessing it does at the moment.

Comment: Maybe the dates on this month, which are selected on Calendar, but how take Entity from External List imported from CRM, and how eit Entity. I don't see after adding to project BBC Model -> BCS Meta Man Data Explorer

Comment: I don't use BCS Meta Man, so I'm afraid I can't help you with that.