# BCS External List 2000 maximum record count

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is there a way to do some type of pagination?  Display 2000 record, then click to get the next 2000 records?

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9628.sharepoint-2010-best-practice-row-limits-in-external-lists.aspx

taken from the link above:

How to use paging in BCS

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/85142d3d-2a21-4e06-b4fa-388e3a6a05e0/

SharePoint 2010 External List Paging – Server Side

http://lightningtools.com/bcs/sharepoint-2010-external-list-paging-server-side/

Paging and sorting with BCS

[Paging and sorting with BCS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/paging-and-sorting-with-bcs)