# SharePoint 2013 Unexpected Error while creating lookup column to use external list

Tags: sharepoint-server, lookup-column, external-content-type

I am using SharePoint Server 2013. In that I am creating a custom column which lookup to an external list.

My ECT is based on an SQL Server table and I have created the external list in the site. I have used `read` and `readlist` operations. Than after I can see this in my site. But when I create lookup column based on this external list, Error occurs **"Sorry, something went wrong" error page with Correlation ID: a2fa749d-af7b-e022-9b7a-7fa53c48783a"**.

I had done some research and tried setting the Allow unlimited length in document libraries flag, but this isn't resolved it. I don't understand what the issue as I can see my external list.

Can anyone help on this??

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of the ULS log, otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running into the 2000 item limit for BCS, which you could increase but may still not be able to resolve your issue completely.

### First Option

Here is a similar question: [BCS External Content Type with 20,000+ items (O365)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91292/bcs-external-content-type-with-20-000-items-o365)

The accepted answer says:

> I had a similar issue this morning, with an external dataset with
>   around 100,000 records. The way I worked around it was to create a SQL
>   stored procedure to do the Read List operation, rather than querying
>   the data directly. The Read Item operation can still be linked
>   directly to the list, rather than requiring a second stored procedure.

### Second Option

However I would also point you to [this blog](http://sympmarc.com/2014/02/18/getting-around-sharepoints-threshold-limits-for-large-reference-lists/), which uses a slightly different approach to get the functionality working.

> The data I originally had received for the cities and towns was in a
>   CSV file. I found a nice little site that would convert the [CSV format
>   to JSON](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) (bookmark this one; you’ll need it in this JSON-oriented
>   world).
>
> Once I had the JSON file uploaded to a Document Library, the code
>   below is what I used to set up the autocomplete. We wanted the
>   autocomplete to allow multiple choices, so there’s a little monkeying
>   around to enable that. It wasn’t tremendously peppy (19,000 cities,
>   after all), but it worked.

So if your data is static you could just jump over to Marc's blog and use that code. If it isn't there is still some work you'd need to do to get some sort of cache running that gives you JSON dynamically. But in that case I think the first option is a better choice.